# Android Samsung S7 Auto boot on charger plug Script not working

Tags: boot, automation, root-access

I have successfully rooted my samsung Galaxy S7 using this tutorialhow-to-root-galaxy-s7-on-android-6-0-1-marshmallow/

Now i want to boot my mobile on charger plug when mobile is off. i found my lpm file in system/bin/ using ES file browser and changing lpm file content to

```
#!/system/bin/sh
/system/bin/reboot
```

and also tried

```
#!/system/bin/sh
su
/system/bin/reboot
```

and also tried

```
/system/bin/reboot
```

But none of method works for me on s7. also change the file permission for file for root,Group&World to `rwx-rwx-rwx`. I don't know why it is not working either i am conduction any mistake or its issue with latest technology of Galaxy S7 that preventing me to do this. It just showing empty battery now with a charging signal. No animation any more and also by replacing orignal file its doing nothing.

when i hit script from `adb shell system/bin/lpm` mobile reboot successfully.

Any help. Thanks is advance.